# Concatenate in a unique term a mix of string and expression

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I would like to make multiple `and` conditions of the form

$x[1] \geq 0 \&\& x[2] \geq 0\cdots \&\& x[n] $

I have tried to generate a vector of x[i] with

```
c = Table[x[[i]] >= 0 , {i, Length[q]}]
d = Table["&&" , {i, Length[q] - 1}]
dd = ToRiffle[c, d]
```

This gives

```
{x[[1]] >= 0, "&&", x[[2]] >= 0, "&&", x[[3]] >= 0, "&&", 
 x[[4]] >= 0, "&&", x[[5]] >= 0}
```

Now I do not know how to transform this list in an unique expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
q = Range[5];
c = Array[x[#] >= 0 &, {Length[q]}];

And @@ c
```

> x[1] >= 0 && x[2] >= 0 && x[3] >= 0 && x[4] >= 0 && x[5] >= 0

Also,

```
ToExpression @ ToString @ Row @ Riffle[c, "&&"]
```

or

```
foo = Composition[ToExpression, ToString, Row, Riffle[#, "&&"] &];
foo @ c
```

> x[1] >= 0 && x[2] >= 0 && x[3] >= 0 && x[4] >= 0 && x[5] >= 0

Answer (score 4):

```
Array[x[#] >= 0 &, 5, 1, And]
```

> ```
> x[1] >= 0 && x[2] >= 0 && x[3] >= 0 && x[4] >= 0 && x[5] >= 0
> ```